# Zend Framework routing to image folder without using apache or nginx

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

I wish to know how to route to specific folder inside routes.ini,

what i mean or what i want is that i have upload folder with subfolders like 300x200 and images inside those subfolders - some-title-image.jpg

i want route like :

/image-some-title-image-1 to be image path and image (see there is no extension of file)

image - action of controller media
some-title-image - name of file
1 - id of article

I know how to make this on apache and nginx but i dont want this because i want system to be easy to administrate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep images away from hitting PHP through either Apache/nginx. Will slow down the number of requests you can handle a lot.

If you want to handle it through routes.ini then you can use a regular expression based route type http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html

**Edit**

The RegExp you would need is - image-[a-z]*. Put this with the example they have given in the docs. The matched string can be put in a variable using which you can find out which image to display.

Still would advise against this. Would kill the server.

Comment: can u please make an example? I can see the script is a bit slow then i expected because of this route true PHP

Comment: Edited the answer with the regular expression that should work for you.